# Handle FileUploadBase.SizeLimitExceededException

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

When I upload file bigger than 100MB, Tomcat throws org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.SizeLimitExceededException. I want to handle this and redirect when file is bigger than 100MB. This is my handler, but the program doеs not get there. The exception is thrown by Tomcat, not by me. Neither of my methods thows this exception.

```
public ModelAndView handleLargeFileException(FileUploadBase.SizeLimitExceededException e) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:add");
    modelAndView.addObject("title", "Error");
    modelAndView.addObject("largeFile", true);

    return modelAndView;
}
```

Comment: And what's wrong? You cand do that with `try {} catch (org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.SizeLimitExceededException e){ //your other method or message }`

Answer (score 0):

1. **Annotate** your controller class with `@ControllerAdvice` and
2. **Annotate** handler method with `@ExceptionHandler` as below.

   ```
   @ExceptionHandler(SizeLimitExceededException .class)
   public ModelAndView handleLargeFileException() {
       ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
       modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:add");
       modelAndView.addObject("title", "Error");
       modelAndView.addObject("largeFile", true);

       return modelAndView;
   }
   ```

Refer [**this**](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring) example for more details.